# Traefik config file location using docker

Tags: docker, traefik

Traefik's [Getting Started](https://docs.traefik.io/) guid is difficult to follow in any step by step fashion. It has the following problems:

1. [Getting Started](https://docs.traefik.io/) suggests running `traefik` as a command, but no commands can be run on the `traefik` image and you must instead use `traefik:alpine`, even to shell into the container with `docker exec -it ...`.
2. [Getting Started](https://docs.traefik.io/) makes hardly any mention of a `traefik.toml` file.
3. #1 makes a new reader confused as to weather traefik is intended to be run as a container that automatically updates per newly deployed containers like [jwilder's nginx proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) or if it's intended to be run on a docker host.

Their original `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: '3' 

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker #--consul --consul.endpoint=127.0.0.1:8500 # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
```

Then you can run it with:

```
docker-compose up -d reverse-proxy
```

This is fine and you can add new services here and specify new labels like the one above, i.e. `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami-other.docker.localhost`.

You can test this with curl, specifying the host heading like so:

```
curl -H Host:whoami.docker.localhost http://127.0.0.1
```

**Issue 1)**

Line 5 must be changed to use the image `traefik:alpine`.

```
    image: traefik:alpine # The official Traefik docker image
```

You can now actually `docker exec` this container. You can only use `sh` (not `/bin/bash`) on the alpine image. We can now do the following:

```
docker exec -it traefik_reverse-proxy_1 sh
docker exec -it traefik_reverse-proxy_1 traefik --help
```

**Issue 2)**

From the default `docker-compose.yml`, there is no mention of a `traefik.toml` file. Even if I `docker-compose up -d [some_new_service]` and can reach those services, shelling into the container has no `traefik.toml` file. It's **nowhere** in the container, despite that per the bottom of [Basics](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/), it says looks for it default locations such as `/etc/traefik/` and `$HOME/.traefik/` and `.` or the working directory. Is this referring to the host or the container? In the container I run `grep` `find` and only see the binary:

```
/ # find / | grep traefik
/usr/local/bin/traefik
```

Is traefik storing my services configuration in memory?

The next logical page in the documentation ([Basics](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/)), immediately starts detailing configuration of the `traefik.toml`, but I have to such file to experiment with.

I had to to back to [Getting Started](https://docs.traefik.io/) read at the bottom of that page to find that using a static `traefik.toml` file must be specified in a volume when they suggest using their official image and running like this:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 -v $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml traefik
```

So with this, I change the `volumes` section in the original `docker-compose.yml` under the service `reverse-proxy` to use something similar:

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
  - $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
```

Even with this, I don't have a base `traefik.toml` file to even use (there isn't even one in the [examples folder of their GitHub](https://github.com/containous/traefik/tree/v1.7/examples)). I had to go [find one](http://defaultEntryPoints%20=%20[%22http%22]%20%20[entryPoints]%20%20%20[entryPoints.http]%20%20%20address%20=%20%22:80%22%20%20[docker]%20endpoint%20=%20%22unix:///var/run/docker.sock%22%20domain%20=%20%22docker.localhost%22%20exposedByDefault%20=%20false), but wasn't even sure how it would apply to the existing configuration of services I had running (i.e. `whoami` and/or `whoami-other`). Finally, running `find / | grep traefik` on the container shows the same `traefik.toml` file in `/etc/traefik/traefik.toml`, but it has no mention of the services (which I can still reach with `curl -H Host:whoami.docker.localhost http://127.0.0.1` from my docker host). **Where is the configuration then?**

Comment: Rather than spite you anger, just read the doc...
Sample file is right there :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/v1.7/traefik.sample.toml

referenced in the getting started just before the docker command  you wrote.

Comment: @Noki I think this is traefik 1.7 ; PO using traefik 2.x

Comment: could you paste your toml file here, I can not access it somehow.

Comment: @SemihKekül, PO, is traefik < to 2.x because of the frontends labels used in his docker-compose file

Comment: @Noki I think you are right, sorry about that, but does not the line:
image: traefik 
means getting the latest image which is 2.x . If that is the case the configuration of PO may be totaly wrong.

Comment: didn't see it this way but you're right too ! There is probably, a misconfiguration issue. Maybe the 24th of July there traefik v2 wasn't released yet, didn't checked

Comment: It's been a while but the only way I was able to get this working was to interact with docker using the Python API. toml configurations were being completely ignored.

Comment: @Displayname could you share how exactly you got it working?

Answer (score 0):

It is here
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/v2.0/traefik.sample.toml
Somehow the traefik documents is confusing for newbie (I am).